# Best way to encrypt user password via command line Ruby client to authenticate with a Rails application

Tags: ruby, authentication, encryption, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Background**: We currently have a Rails application that uses Devise & LDAP for authentication.  Users simply provide their user & password to sign-in/login and establish a session via a browser. Because we use LDAP we don't need (or want) to store passwords in our Rails app.  This works great.  We also have a Ruby command line utility that has limited functionality and is primarily used for backend automation, but users can use the client CLI to perform certain actions in our app.  Now we want to add authentication to our Ruby client (supported on Windows & Linux).

So what's the best way to send a user's password to our Rails application for authentication?  The catch is we don't want user's to enter their passwords in clear text on the command line (for various reasons).

**Proposal:**
I was thinking about using openssl to create a utility in our Ruby client that allows users to store and encrypt their passwords (with perhaps other config info) in a local encrypted file.  Our Ruby client could then send this encrypted config file on all HTTPS calls to our Rails app.  On the Rails side we could decrypt the file, extract the password and authenticate the user via Devise LDAP before allowing the requested action.

**I can think of a few pitfalls with this design and curious if anyone has a better solution or advice?**

Note: This is an internal tool so we don't need to be paranoid about security, at the same time we don't want anyone to get someone else's corp password. Ideally this solution also has to prevent any of our app developers from being able to access user passwords as well.

Comment: So are you asking about the transmission or about how to store the credentials on the client side? What platform?

Comment: Our client is supported on Windows and Linux.  Per above I'm curious if my current proposal of using openssl to store passwords in encrypted files is the best approach.

Comment: If the user just has to send the file (which presumably is just on disk somewhere) then it smells of obfuscation to me. Sure the user can't extract passwords from the file, but they don't need to because the rails app does it for them

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is rather old but the answer can be useful for others.

I think openssl is your best bet. You don't have to create the password storage utility yourself.  You can maybe extend it if you need to.

There is already a tool in a gem called keybox (created by Jeremy Hinegardner).
From the rubyforge.org (homepage of the application):

- Keybox provides 2 command line applications, keybox and kpg

  - keybox: a pure ruby command line password storage application that uses the OpenSSL libraries included with ruby for the encryption.
  - kpg: pure ruby implementation of the Automated Password Generator (apg)
    program. It attempts to implemented all the functionality of ‘apg’,
    but it is not completely compatible.

You can find it at http://keybox.rubyforge.org/ with docs at http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/keybox/1.2.1.